# Adding a '%' after each value automatically

Tags: vba

I'm not a huge fan of formatting cells as a percent in Excel because it automatically multiplies the value by 100.

I want to write my own VBA function that looks for a change in value in a particular cell and adds a '%' to the end of it.

How can I write some code to look for changes automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the format string to `0\%`.
The `\` escapes the percent character and prevents Excel from multiplying it by 100.

Comment: Ok, one thing that isn't working is if I type '0', all I see is:

'%'

I would like the zero to display

Comment: Also, I want to be able to programmatically change these formats. 
What VBA code is necessary to change the format of a cell?

Comment: `someRange.NumberFormat = "0\%"`